# DHL's Tracking API (Shipment Tracking - Unified) Suddenly Returns 404 Statuses

Tags: rest, get, dhl

As of April 28th, 2023, [DHL's Unified Shipment Tracking](https://developer.dhl.com/api-reference/shipment-tracking#get-started-section/) API started returning 404 statuses for all calls to this endpoint using a tracking number that used to return a 200 status:

`https://api-eu.dhl.com/track/shipments?trackingNumber=GM545115623000247160`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out as I was asking:

The **service** parameter is now required. We track DHL ecommerce solutions so the new endpoint is:

`https://api-eu.dhl.com/track/shipments?trackingNumber=GM545115623000247160&service=ecommerce`

What's frustrating is that I either missed or never received an email regarding this API change and I could have sworn it wasn't listed as a required parameter before in their [API reference](https://developer.dhl.com/api-reference/shipment-tracking#reference-docs-section). Hopefully this helps anyone else that has this issue.